# Authorization code for github used in java via scribe library

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I am trying to access the github api(https://api.github.com/user) as mentioned in scribe library example
(https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples/GitHubExample.java)

which return me this authorization url

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=156d37xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8282%2FReportsServer%2Fsuccessful.jsp&state=secret846593

but now i have to give the authorization code as mentioned in above link example

```
 final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

            System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
            System.out.println();

            // Obtain the Authorization URL
            System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
            final String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
            System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
            System.out.println("Now go and authorize ScribeJava here:");
            System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
            System.out.println("And paste the authorization code here");
            System.out.print(">>");
            final String code = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("And paste the state from server here. We have set 'secretState'='" + secretState + "'.");
            System.out.print(">>");
            final String value = in.nextLine();
            if (secretState.equals(value)) {
                System.out.println("State value does match!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ooops, state value does not match!");
                System.out.println("Expected = " + secretState);
                System.out.println("Got      = " + value);
                System.out.println();
            }

            // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
            System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
            final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(code);
            System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
            System.out.println("(The raw response looks like this: " + accessToken.getRawResponse() + "')");
            System.out.println();
```

but the problem is that how can i get the authorization code and Can any one tell me what the authorization code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

So far you are at step 1: that is, creating the authorization URL that tells the server about the application (details like your client id, redirect URL etc..)

in any OAuth flow, there are 3 parties involved

1. User
2. An app that is requesting the access token
3. Service Provider (Github in this case)

Let's say I am the GitHub user who is on the website managed by you. Your website wants to access my data residing on GitHub. Your website can not directly retrieve any of my protected data from GitHub without `access-token`.

How do you get this access token?

- Your website registers as a client on GitHub and gets `client-secret`
- Everytime website needs some user's `access-token`, first it identifies itself via `authorization-url` to GitHub by sending identification params.
  In your case, you need to paste that `authorization-url` into the browser to continue. On production, your website should redirect user onto `authorization-url`.
- Github then validates the identification details of the website and if they are all good, it asks the user (me in this case) whether I want to give access to my protected data to your website.
- If I say yes, GitHub will call the URL you specified in `redirect_url` param along with `request-token` (aka `authorization-code`)
- Your website will read this `request-token`, make the server call to GitHub and exchange it with `access-token`
- Once the website has my `access-token`, it can request my protected data to GitHub.

Comment: As i am doing in local server and after paste that authorization url , github return  this redirect_url along with parameter .. i want to know that is it possible in local server to redirect the authorization url automatically without pasting that in browser manually because i done this via jsp & sevlet

Comment: Yes that’s absolutely possible. What you need to do is, once you get request for github from client, create the authorisation url and call response.sendRedirect(authorizationUrl). That’s it!

Comment: But i think we can't get the authorization code because it comes with redirect_url  as parameter after calling authorizationUrl with response.sendRedirect() method

Comment: `redirect_url` is your app URL where GitHub will redirect the user after success authorization. Please read the answer carefully, it's all explained there.

Comment: yeah i have read it but i have some confusion that is i have to pass the authorization code which comes with redirect_url to get access-token via scribe library method  service.getAccessToken(code) as you can see in the above given code

Comment: i have just got your point but can you tell me how to handle callback url to extract authorization code  for getting access token via scribe library reference example

Comment: Create gist: https://gist.github.com/yogesh-badke/63d9ca920ca04784223631963a83dc0f

Comment: Your given architecture saves my extra effort.