# Java Webserver for oAuth2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I am trying to write a web server in a native Java application for the purposes of an oAuth2 authentication flow. (The web server is the client, not the server in the flow.)

I have tried starting a web server using HTTP Server

```
public static void startServer() throws IOException {
    int port = 13370;
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "This is the response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}
```

However what this does is that it will host a webpage at     http://127.0.0.1:13370/test, and display the response there. In a oAuth flow, the server will send the authorization code like
    http://127.0.0.1:13370/?code=[code]&state=[state]
which the above web server is not expecting.

Is there a way to configure the server to be expecting the response?

Comment: Accepting the authorization code from the authorization server is pretty much similar to write code like API I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of standard oAuth, you can specify `return_url` when you hit `authorization-url`.

For example, this is how you tell service provider, where to redirect after authorization.

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=156d37xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A13370%2Ftest&state=secret846593
```

In above url, `redirect_uri` is http://localhost:13370/test

After this change, you should be able to capture `code` in `MyHandler#handle` method.

Refer to [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49234099/1891456) for whole oAuth flow.